# Js document.write() problem while printing specific element

Tags: javascript, printing

I was using jQuery.print.js on jQuery 3
to print specific divs in my project it was working fine,
but today in the morning I see that the print button is not working after that I started tracing the error and I come to know that the jQuery.print.js uses document.write() function which is no longer supported in google chrome

so if anybody has the proper solution or alternative for printing specific div on same page so please help me

```
frameWindow = frameWindow.contentWindow || frameWindow.contentDocument || frameWindow;
var wdoc = frameWindow.document || frameWindow.contentDocument || frameWindow;
if(options.doctype) {
   wdoc.write(options.doctype);
}
   wdoc.write(content);
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: Drop off jQuery.print.js and use MediaQueries instead.

Comment: how media queries will work when i click the print button to print specific div

Comment: The linked article teaches you to use MediaQueries.

Comment: can you please suggest to me an example